# Determine minimal polynomial without arguing about irreducibility

Tags: field-theory, minimal-polynomials

Let $E/K$ be a field extension and let $\alpha \in E$ be algebraic over $K$. Let $f \in K[x]$.

My question is, if I have the following:

- $f(\alpha)=0$
- $f$ is monic
- $\deg(f) = [E : K]$

Can I then conclude that

- $f$ is the minimal polynomial for $\alpha$ over $K$?

Then I don't have to prove that $f$ is irreducible over $K$.

Answer (score 2):

Take any element $a$ in $K$ and $f(x)=(x-a)^n, n=[E:F]$ $f$ is not the minimal polynomial of $a$.

Comment: Do you have a counter example if $a \in E$ is algebraic over $K$?

Comment: Take any $a$ with minimal polynomial $P$ of degree $l<n=[E:K]$, and consider $PX^{n-l}$.